# Magento Session/ Cache acts really weirdly

Tags: php, javascript, magento, caching, session-variables

I'm setting a Magento session variable within the footer.phtml as shown below

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPopup('1'); ?>
```

Then I  access it through a javascript written in next few lines of footer.phtml.

```
var val = <?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPopup()?>;
```

But when I try to access this session variable from the home page of my web site it shows as blank. Means not set. but if I go to a different page, I can see that the session variable is set to the value I wanted. 
Then if I go back to the home page, variable as blank (Not set) again.

Any idea what could be the reason for this funny behaviour?

Note : I have my Footer.php (Block file) overwritten in my local code space, and comment out all cashing stuff in the contractor. This is to make sure footer.phtml not get being cached.

But we also have full page cache enabled, not sure this cause the issue, if so how to fix that without disabling full page cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage to fix this issue by adding following 2 lines to `app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Footer.php`,

```
protected function _construct()
{
    //Disabling footer from getting cashed by FPC
    $cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance();
    $cache->banUse('full_page');
}
```

Comment: Its good that you answered your own question. It will help someone with the similar issues. I want to add something to it. Can't it be made such that you only separate out the code that you do not want to cache and let the Footer cache, because this will ultimately impact the performance?

Comment: @DushyantJoshi Yes, I reckon hole punching is the technique to do that, but with the time I had, looking in to that option was not an option :). May be later... I would try to do a hole punch for my bit of dynamic content.